# add an Alert under certain circumstances

Tags: opportunity, opportunity-lineitem, button, popup

The users of my org have a needs but I don't know how to help them. In my Organization there are two objects Opportunity and P&L. Every Opportunity have one and only one P&L where the agents insert more information about the Opportunity's products. The problem is that: 
The users can add Opportunity's products after the P&L is created. They want an Alert that says :"P&L  already exists, go and modify it."

My question is: Can I add an alert on the button "add product"   that pops up only when P&L already exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `Add Product` is a custom button, you can make it a JavaScript button and add your validation logic similar to below:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/35.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/35.0/apex.js")} 

var queryResult = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id from P_AND_L_OBJECT_API_NAME where Opportunity__c ='{!Opportunity.Id}' limit 1");

records = queryResult.getArray("records"); 

if(records.size()>0){
   alert('P&L already exists');
}else{
   //navigate to page for adding new Opportunity Product
}
```